# Execution policies considerations when setting up PowerShell custom profile

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I am migrating my configurations from old computer to a new one and have run into an issue with my PowerShell custom profile file. I placed it in the /documents/WindowsPowerShell folder just like in the old system, but when opening the shell in the new system, I get an error message:

> profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on
> this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

I checked the link and understand the source of the error message to an extent but I am not clear on how to set up the profile execution without also losing the security benefits Execution Policies are providing me atm.

Any advice on how to set up my profile without whitelisting the execution of all scripts?

I am on Windows 10 Pro (20H2), build 19042.746

Comment: Setting it to `RemoteSigned` will give protection from unsigned scripts downloaded from the internet but still allow you to run your own scripts.

Comment: Thanks, did that. I had originally hoped for something more fine grained like whitelisting a directory but I guess this will have to do.

Comment: There is no Whitelisting via Powershell natively, As documented, there are 3 levels Machine, Use, Process. You can have a machine at RemoteSigned, and a User at whatever level you choose. As stated/documented by MS, ***the restriction policy is not a security boundary***. It is there to prevent accidentally running scripts and for alerting admin via PS Auditing that scripts are being run. There are many ways to bypass it. [15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy). WhiteListing is what SRP policies are for.